# Modifying a string in a function in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work, but I'm not really sure.

```
void main(void){ 
    char* s = "aBCde F. hjiodhfvev, . efof Gh";
    to_lower_case(s); 
    printf("%s",s); 
}
```

The function `to_lower_case()` is just a random function that does what its name suggests. I guess it has something to do with the string being declared as a `constant`.

Comment: And where is the code for `to_lower_case`?

Comment: Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior (so, you should never assign a string literal to a `char*`). Instead declare the variable as a char array, which *copies* the string literal: `char s[] = "the string literal";`

Comment: Also, `void` main? Are you planning to learn `premature C` then unlearn it to learn latest standards?

Comment: There's nothing wrong about a void main.

Comment: @Nerd: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for a complete disquisition on why `void main()` is only faintly acceptable on MS Windows and essentially nowhere else.

Comment: Note: finding the dupe was easy - I copypasted your exact title into a popular search engine and got: 'About 1,140,000 results', with the dupe as top entry:(

Comment: I'll accept it as dupe. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem

```
char* s = "aBCde F. hjiodhfvev, . efof Gh";
```

String literals (the ones in quotes) are read-only. You cannot modify them.

You should declare it as

```
char s[] = "aBCde F. hjiodhfvev, . efof Gh";
```

Comment: Well, are you sure this is the issue? This could be, but everything `to_lower_case()` does is still under the hoods..

Comment: This was the issue, although I should've included the code for the lower case function aswell.

Comment: @sjsam yes I'm sure, even without knowing what `to_lower_case()` does. This is a common pitfall for beginners. Non-beginner do not make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Strings provided as string-literals are read-only. You will need to copy the string to mutable memory first:

```
char* s_readonly = "foobar";
size_t s_length = strlen( s_readonly );
char* s_mutable = malloc( s_length + 1 );
assert( s_mutable );
errno_t err = strcopy_s( s_mutable, s_length, s_readonly );
assert( err == 0 );
to_lower_case( s_mutable ); 
puts( s_mutable );
free( s_mutable );
```

- My code performs an explicit copy to the heap. This code could be made simpler by assigning the string literal to a `char[n]`-type. This has the advantage of allowing static `sizeof()` to work which is faster `O(1)` than `strlen` which is `O(n)`.
- `printf("%s\n", s)` can be replaced with `puts` which is faster as there's no format-string to parse.
- I use `strcopy_s` over the insecure `strcopy`. Always check the returned error code!
- And always call `free` after `malloc`. If you're dealing with short strings you could use `alloca` instead which is faster and doesn't require the use of `free`.

Alternatively, just this:

```
char s_mutable[] = "foobar";
to_lower_case( s_mutable ); 
puts( s_mutable );
```

The advantage here (besides terseness) is that `s_mutable` is mutable right away, and it means that `sizeof( s_mutable ) == 12`.

Comment: `malloc(s_length + 1)` for the trailing 0 character!